# Does an Interdiction Nullifier module allow escape against a Heavy Interdiction Cruiser's Infinity Point?

Tags: eve-online

Recently my Nereus was blown up - typical eve-online activity.

I made the error of undocking in low sec while a Broadsword was in range. After my ship's destruction, I learned that the Broadsword is a Heavy Interdiction Cruiser, which can use its Warp Disruption Field Generator module on a single ship in low sec to create infinite warp disruption on that ship. This mode is available in low sec, while the bubble mode is restricted to null sec.

This happened the day before the patch, which added new Interdiction Nullifier modules. These modules can be fitted on Industrial ships, like the Nereus.

The module's description is:

> Temporarily nullifies the effects of warp disrupt probes and mobile warp disruptors.

Does this module counter the single target mode of the Warp Disruption Field Generator?

Comment: This isn't a new mechanic, I remember using scripted hics to catch blockade runners with huge amounts of warp core stabs in high sec even. Some 5-6 years ago. Also interdiction nullifiers have been around forever too on t3 cruisers. They only help against bubbles, nothing else.

Comment: The patch notes state that Interdiction Modules and blueprints are new.
The descriptions on these modules are new, and misleading, imo.

https://www.eveonline.com/news/view/patch-notes-version-19-04

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Scripted HI modules work like scrams/points. Nullification gets you out of bubbles only, same as for Interceptors and T3 Cruisers with the relevant subsystem.

Answer (score 2):

To complement the accepted answer - the heavy dictors' point strength is not infinite when loaded with scripts. The scripts make it essentially a disruptor or a scrambler module with strength of 100 points (and of course there is no technically a way to overcome such a great number with stabilizer modules).